# npm ERR! errno -13 when Installing npm module to windows 10 with wsl

Tags: node.js, npm, mongoose, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having an issue to install mongoose module to my project. I have already installed it globally and in other projects. But it is not installing in the current project. 
I faced this issue many times. It sometimes installs the module without error and sometimes not.

I don't know what's the problem. It throws the "npm ERR! errno -13" error and says "The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user"

[image: screenshot of mongoose installation]
[image: screenshot of upgrade npm]

I have tried this npm command: "**sudo npm I mongoose --save**" with and without sudo. It throws same error. But it worked in the last project.

It also throws an error when I try to upgrade npm

Please help me to figure out the problem and solve it.

Comment: Your facing for permission issue, please refer this https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxvybxYFq2o

Comment: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92 discusses why `sudo` should never be used with `npm`. It addresses the security risk, and the problem of the forced install not belonging to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://hackersandslackers.com/fixing-your-npm-installation/

Why does this happen? Because by default, the post-install scripts attempt to run as the current user. Since the current user doesn't have permissions to mess with packages installed globally, the installation ultimately fails. To fix this, we need to reinstall Node the correct way.